# Demora na publicação de APP - Play store

Tags: android, google-play

Bom dia, Estou em dúvida sobre a publicação do meu primeiro APP publico na loja da google. Fiz a publicação no dia 15/08 e até hoje (20/08) o APP ainda esta com status de 'Rascunho'. Minha impressão é que essa demora não é normal. Alguem pode me dar alguma dica? abaixo seguem prints da loja.

No inicio eu achava que era normal, pela mensagem que estava sendo apresentada (imagem 3) *"Para proteger os usuários, a revisão detalhada do app levará um pouco mais de tempo. Saiba mais"*. Mas a demora esta demais, será que falta algo? Ou posso ter feito algo errado?

[image: Todos os itens obrigatórios preenchidos]

[image: Botão de iniciar lançamento DESABILITADO]

[image: Mensagem]

Comment: Também estou com essa dúvida...

Comment: Por fim, como criei nova conta, não voltei mais ao tópico. Mas na nova conta o processo ocorreu normalmente. Não desvendei o misterio, mas deveria ser alguma configuração na conta antiga.

Comment: se o status e de "Rascunho" significa que vc ainda nao submeteu ele a publicacao, ainda falta alguns passos.

Comment: publiquei 2 app no dia 16/09 hoje e dias 03/10 faz 16 dias já, e ainda esta em analise tenho outros apps publicados que demorou no máximo 7 dias mais esses 2 últimos são os mais demorados :(

Answer (score 5):

Interessante sua pergunta, para mim esta servindo como um alerta pois não estava sabendo dessa mudança.

Apos uma pesquisa rápida achei algumas noticias dessa semana, que basicamente fala que o Google esta com uma **nova politica de pelo menos 3 dias* de review**, e que isso só esta sendo noticiado porque um desenvolvedor de jogos publicou [em seu blog](https://www.choiceofgames.com/2019/08/google-warns-developers-that-all-new-apps-require-three-days-for-approval/) o problema.
<sup>*O Google atualizou o texto em usa pagina de ajuda e **agora (13/09/2019) o texto fala em 7 dias**</sup>

Agora na pagina de [Ajuda do Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=pt-br), tem a seguinte **observação**

<sub>em 13/09/2019 ↓</sub>

> **Observação:** em algumas contas de desenvolvedor, a revisão detalhada dos apps levará um pouco mais de tempo, para proteger melhor os usuários. **Isso pode aumentar o prazo da análise para até sete dias (ou mais, em casos excepcionais)**. Você receberá uma notificação no **Painel** do app com a duração estimada desse processo.

<sub>em 23/08/2019 ↓</sub>

> <sup>**Observação:** em algumas contas de desenvolvedor, a revisão detalhada dos apps levará um pouco mais de tempo, para proteger melhor os usuários. Você receberá uma notificação no **Painel** do app com a duração estimada desse processo. **É recomendável ajustar o plano para incluir um período de espera mínimo de três dias entre o envio e a publicação do app**.</sup>

<sub>em 21/08/2019 ↓</sub>

> <sup>**Note:** For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to thoroughly review your app(s) to help better protect users. You’ll receive a notification on your app's **Dashboard** about how long this should take. **We recommend that you adjust your planning to include a buffer period of at least three days between submitting your app and going live**.</sup>

Agora olhando suas imagem nota-se que a medida de tempo que eles falam:

```
Você receberá uma notificação no Painel do app com 
 a duração estimada desse processo.
```

No momento ainda é **levará um pouco mais de tempo**.

<sub>Link para algumas noticias em Inglês [[1]](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/08/19/google-play-expands-store-app-review/)[[2]](https://gameworldobserver.com/2019/08/20/google-review-android-apps/)</sub>

Comment: Sim, também vi algumas notícias a respeito dessa demora de 3 dias. Mas passando disso já começa a me preocupar. Amanha fecha uma semana da data de publicação e meu prazo vai estourando. Mas obrigado pela tua resposta, tenho a mesma visão que a tua.

Comment: Parece que ainda não tem uma forma de apressar essa review, na apple tem uma forma de pedir prioridade *(não sei como funciona pois nunca tive que pedir)*. Esse **levará um pouco mais de tempo** talvez seja uma indicação que vai demorar mais de 3 dias, a confusão pôde esta sendo causada porque estamos acostumados ao publicar instantâneo, acho que eles deveriam ter colocado, *"pode demorar mais de X dias"*. Talvez valha apena, depois que sua app for aprovada ou recusa, nos informar quanto tempo levou.

Comment: **Me parece que e seu primeiro aplicativo no Play Store, esse pode ser o motivo do seu review demorar mais de 3 dias.** -- *Essa informação pode ser irrelevante --* A Apple até um tempo atrás demorava +/- 7 dias para aprovar um app, só agora que eles conseguiram fazer uma rotina *(ou ficaram menos rigorosos)* para aprovar um app em 1 ou 2 dias, pode ser que o google enfrente o mesmo problema nessa nova fase da Play Store

Comment: Realmente falta uma comunicação mais objetiva da loja. O APP segue com o mesmo status e aviso. O prazo que eu tinha era hoje. Quando publicar, eu informo;

Comment: Talvez valha a pena você entrar em contato com eles. [Contact Google Play developer support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994)

Comment: Nada ainda. Mandei alguns e-mails e não tive retorno ainda. Agora o evento que era a proposta do APP passou. Tive que disponibilizar a apk em outro servidor. pqp

Comment: Desisti de aguardar a publicação, criei uma nova conta de desenvolvedor, realizei os mesmos passos e publiquei na nova conta. EM 2 dias o APP estava disponível na loja. Ainda não sei o motivo, mas deve ser algum problema com a conta.